# How to increase the file size of source input xml file in Informatica?

Tags: xml, file, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm loading XML file in to my oracle DB using Informatica. During which the XML file having size greater than 3 GB is not getting processed. The session fails with out any errors in session logs. Hence we are using a unix script to split the xml in to 1.5 GB files and loading it . Is there a way to increase the size of XML file processed using the session properties itself?

Answer (score 1):

According to Informatica docs the file size for XML is only 10MB.
But I am sure you are not reading it as an XML, instead as a flat file but as a stream of data and uploading it  as blob or clob, isnt it  ? Is that the case   ? 
Can you share the mapping steps that you are performing ?

https://kb.informatica.com/proddocs/Product%20Documentation/5/PC_101_XMLGuide_en.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the way I would approach would be simple. 
Nothing should be complex and huge. Even if they are files.

I do know a few folks/orgs who process huge files in parallel processing mode in Informatica and debugging has been a nightmare for those folks/orgs. (Keep it all simple and in manageable sizes so that one can face it easily for debugging, testing, refactoring, etc. etc. purposes.  ).

That's when , the power of generating manageable size files at the source is requested.

Sorry to ask this Q..... but... for a better solution, let us know... who generated this huge file? 
Was it generated by some source system / source script?

Comment: We generate a file from ouR DB and we are exactly doing the same splitting file in to smaller chunks and loading it but will there be any easier way is the search